# Tiny "fuzzy" wispy strings on the entire surface of the model?

Tags: creality-ender-3, stringing

I have my print settings dialed into a real good spot, but there's one obstacle that's preventing them from coming out flawless; somehow, my print has "fuzz" everywhere. Not traditional stringing like you get from filament oozing while travelling from section to section, nor do I mean over-extrusion that causes the outer walls to sag or bubble out.

The final shape/texture of my models are perfect - there's just wispy little hairs sticking out all over the model. They are not even really visible unless you hold it up to the light, or against a dark background.

Here's an image of the wing from a dragon I printed. Notice the top edge of the part and how it looks like it's made of cotton or something? That's how it looks everywhere.

[image: Close up of dragon wing showing cotton effect]

Comment: What material?  What temperature?  What nozzle/layer size?  What retraction-related settings (retraction amount/speed, coast, etc.)?

Comment: PLA, 200c, 0.4mm nozzle, 0.08mm layer. Retracting 6mm / 40mm/s, coast off.

Answer (score 2):

That is the print stringing still. Even thought that you have your printer dialed in, the plastic that is still in the nozzle is still grabbing onto your print and pulling out the nozzle just a tad. This, as far as I know, is unavoidable. The best solution that I could think of fixing this (as far as having your print come perfect off of the bed) would if a company designed the tips, printer, and filament to perfectly match each other, but until that happens, you are gonna be stuck with a lighter balling up the strings and picking them off.

Answer (score 1):

These stringers are common with PETG.
You can reduce them by:

1. Increasing retraction reduces the stringers, but too much retraction can cause the filament to jam and stop extruding.
2. Lowering the extruder temperature will reduce the stringers, but also reduce adhesion between layers.  Stringers usually aren't an issue on the 1st layer, so you can keep the necessary extrusion temperature for the 1st layer to keep adhesion to the bed.

Your stringers are very short thus difficult to reduce.  One method to get rid of stringers is to expose the print very quickly with the flame of a blow torch.  Important is you don't want to melt the strings.  You want them to burn, so that they are ash and easily removed.  Melting the stringers will distort your print.